# Show that two integrals are equal:

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Can someone show how to get the equality $$\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos^m(x) \sin^m(x) dx = 2^{-m}\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos^m (x) dx$$ with integral substitution? Thanks!

Comment: Hints: 1) $\sin 2x=2\sin x \cos x$ and 2) $\sin(\pi/2-y)=\cos y$.

Comment: @O.L.: Make it him as an answer. :)

Comment: Oh man, I feel dumb now...I totally forgot about trig relations and was just trying u-sub with sines and cosines. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$$\int_0^{\frac\pi2}\sin^mx\cos^mxdx=\frac1{2^m} \int_0^{\frac\pi2}(\sin2x)^mdx$$

$$=\frac1{2^m} \int_0^{\pi}(\sin y)^m\frac{dy}2$$

$$=\frac1{2^m} \int_0^{\frac\pi2}(\sin y)^m\frac{dy}2+\frac1{2^m} \int_{\frac\pi2}^\pi(\sin y)^m\frac{dy}2$$

Put $y=x-\frac\pi2$ and use $$\int_a^bf(x)dx=\int_a^bf(a+b-x)dx\text{  to find }\int_0^{\frac\pi2}(\sin y)^mdy=\int_0^{\frac\pi2}(\cos  y)^mdy$$